# How to prevent a map from reloading

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, plotly

I created a function allowing me to generate maps by filtering on the outcome, the covariates and the month. Outcomes are circles, covariates are polygons, months ares in slider. The covariates are fixed values, only the outcomes change when month vary. So I don't want all the map to reload when I change the month but only the size of the circles changes, and allow the map to reload when only I change the covariate. I want the same for the scatter plot (created with `plotly`) if possible, that is, allow only the dots and slops to change when filtering, and not the background of the plot

```
shinyUI(sidebarLayout(
                                  sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                                               div(style="font-size:10px;",
                                               radioButtons(inputId="outcome",
                                                            label = "Choisir l'outcome",
                                                            choices=c("INCIDENCE","LETALITY")),
                                               selectInput(inputId = "covariable",
                                                           label = "Choisir la covariable",
                                                           choices = c("IDH","UNDER 5 MORTALITY","AGE ABOVE 65",
                                                                       "REFUGEES","POPULATION DENSITY",
                                                                       "EQUALITY LEVEL")),
                                               sliderTextInput(
                                                 inputId = "mois",
                                                 label = "Month:",
                                                 choices = c("APRIL","MAY","JUNE","JULY","AUGUST","SEPTEMBER",
                                                             "OCTOBER","NOVEMBER"),
                                                 selected = "APRIL",
                                                 animate = animationOptions(interval = 2000,
                                                                                      playButton = icon('play', "fa-0.5x"),
                                                                                      pauseButton = icon('pause', "fa-0.5x")))
                                               
                                               )),
                                  
                                  mainPanel(width = 9,
                                            
                                            tags$style(type = "text/css", 
                                                       "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}",
                                                       
                                                       ".leaflet .legend {
                                             font-size: 8px;
                                           line-height: 10px;}",
                                                       
                                                       ".leaflet .legend i{
                                           width: 8px;
                                           height: 8px;
                                           }"
                                            ),
                                            
                                            (fluidRow
                                             (column(7, "CARTOGRAPHY",leafletOutput("mymap")),
                                               column(5, "SCATTER PLOT WITH SLOP",plotlyOutput("plot")))
                                            ))
                                  ))
    
    
    shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {
    
      
     ##########################
      #FOCTION DE REACTIVITE MOIS/OUTCOME/COVARIABLE
      mois<-reactive({input$mois})
      
      outcome <- reactive({input$outcome})
      
      covariable <- reactive({input$covariable})
     
      ######################
      #CREATION DES MAPS
      #########################
       output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
        production_carte(outcome = outcome(),covar = covariable(),
                         mois = mois() ) })
      #############################
      ##CREATION DE LA PENTE DE CORRELATION
      ######################################
      output$plot<-renderPlotly({
          production_regression(outcome = outcome(),covar = covariable(),
                             mois = mois() )
      })
      
      })
```

Here is a picture of my application

[image]

below the function allowing the creation of map:

```
#FONCTION PRODUCTION
#################################################################################
production_carte <- function(outcome,covar,mois) {
  
  # coef_rad = 1
  # outcome <- as.character(outcome)
  # covar <- as.character(covar)
  # mois <- as.character(mois)
  title_covar =""
  
  if (mois == "APRIL") {
    data_final_mois <- subset(data_final,data_final$date2 ==ymd("2020-04-01"))
  } else if (mois == "MAY") {
    data_final_mois <- subset(data_final,data_final$date2 ==ymd("2020-05-01"))  
  } else if (mois == "JUNE") {
    data_final_mois <- subset(data_final,data_final$date2 ==ymd("2020-06-01"))  
  } else if (mois == "JULY") {
    data_final_mois <- subset(data_final,data_final$date2 ==ymd("2020-07-01")) 
  } else if (mois == "AUGUST") {
    data_final_mois <- subset(data_final,data_final$date2 ==ymd("2020-08-01")) 
  } else if (mois == "SEPTEMBER") {
    data_final_mois <- subset(data_final,data_final$date2 ==ymd("2020-09-01")) 
  } else if (mois == "OCTOBER") {
    data_final_mois <- subset(data_final,data_final$date2 == ymd("2020-10-01")) 
  } else if (mois == "NOVEMBER") {
    data_final_mois <- subset(data_final,data_final$date2 == ymd("2020-11-01")) 
  }
  
  
  data_final_mois -> shape_covid_2
  
  shape_covid_2$IDH <- as.numeric(shape_covid_2$IDH)
  shape_covid_2$density <- as.numeric(as.character(shape_covid_2$density))
  shape_covid_2$Death_blw_5 <- as.numeric(shape_covid_2$Death_blw_5)
  shape_covid_2$rate_abv_65 <- as.numeric(shape_covid_2$rate_abv_65)
  shape_covid_2$refugees <- as.numeric(shape_covid_2$refugees)
  shape_covid_2$IHDI <- as.numeric(shape_covid_2$IHDI)
  shape_covid_2$ratio_cas_pop<-as.numeric(shape_covid_2$ratio_cas_pop)
  shape_covid_2$Letalite<-as.numeric(shape_covid_2$Letalite)
  
  if ( covar == "IDH") {
    covariable <- shape_covid_2$IDH
    bins_idh <- c(0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9)
    pal_idh <- brewer.pal(name="BuGn",n=8)[2:8]
    palette <- colorBin(pal_idh, domain =~covariable,bins = bins_idh,na.color = "transparent")
    popup_covar <- paste("</b>",
                         "<a href='", shape_covid_2$url,
                         "' target='_blank'>"
                         , shape_covid_2$NAME,"</a>","<br/>",
                           "HDI :",round(shape_covid_2$IDH,2)) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)
    title_covar <- paste("Human Development Indicator","</b>","<br/>","Date :",unique(shape_covid_2$date2),"</b>","<br/>","Source : United Nations Development Program")
  } else if (covar == "POPULATION DENSITY") {
    covariable <- shape_covid_2$density
    bins_density <- c(2,20,60,100,200,300,400,650)
    pal_density <- brewer.pal(name="BuPu",n=8)[2:8]
    palette <- colorBin(pal_density, domain =~covariable,bins = bins_density,na.color = "transparent")
    popup_covar <- paste("</b>",
                         "<a href='", shape_covid_2$url,
                         "' target='_blank'>"
                         , shape_covid_2$NAME,"</a>","<br/>","Pop Density :",
                         round(shape_covid_2$density,2),"people/sq.km")
    title_covar <- paste("Population Density (people/sq.km)","</b>","<br/>","Date :",
                         unique(shape_covid_2$date2),"</b>","<br/>","Source : World Databank")
  } else if (covar == "EQUALITY LEVEL") {
    covariable <- shape_covid_2$IHDI
    bins_ineq <- c(0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7)
    pal_ineq <- brewer.pal(name="YlGn",n=6)[2:6]
    palette <- colorBin(pal_ineq, domain =~covariable,bins = bins_ineq,na.color = "transparent")
    popup_covar <- paste("</b>",
                         "<a href='", shape_covid_2$url,
                         "' target='_blank'>"
                         , shape_covid_2$NAME,"</a>","<br/>",
                         "Equality Level :",round(shape_covid_2$IHDI,2))
    title_covar <- paste("Equality Level Indicator","</b>","<br/>","Date :",unique(shape_covid_2$date2),"Source : ?")
  } else if (covar == "UNDER 5 MORTALITY") {
    covariable <- shape_covid_2$Death_blw_5
    bins_u5 <- c(10,20,30,40,60,80,100,120)
    pal_u5 <- brewer.pal(name="YlOrRd",n=8)[2:8]
    palette <- colorBin(pal_u5, domain =~covariable,bins = bins_u5,na.color = "transparent")
    popup_covar <- paste("</b>",
                         "<a href='", shape_covid_2$url,
                         "' target='_blank'>"
                         , shape_covid_2$NAME,"</a>","<br/>",
                         "Under 5 mortality :",round(shape_covid_2$Death_blw_5,2),"child/1000 birth")
    title_covar <- paste("Under five mortality rate (child/1000 birth)","</b>","<br/>","Date:",unique(shape_covid_2$date2),"</b>","<br/>",
                         "Source : UNICEF")
  } else if (covar == "AGE ABOVE 65") {
    covariable <- shape_covid_2$rate_abv_65
    bins_above_65 <- c(1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,7,12)
    pal_above_65 <- brewer.pal(name="YlGnBu",n=8)[2:8]
    palette <- colorBin(pal_above_65, domain =~covariable,bins = bins_above_65,na.color = "transparent")
    popup_covar <- paste("</b>",
                         "<a href='", shape_covid_2$url,
                         "' target='_blank'>"
                         , shape_covid_2$NAME,"</a>","<br/>",
                         "Above 65 pop rate :",round(shape_covid_2$rate_abv_65,2),"%")
    title_covar <- paste("Above 65 population rate (%)","</b>","<br/>","Date :",unique(shape_covid_2$date2),"</b>","<br/>","Source : United Nations Development Program")
  } else if (covar == "REFUGEES") {
    covariable <- shape_covid_2$refugees
    bins_ref <- c(0,0.3,0.6,3,7.2,27,100,950)
    pal_ref <- brewer.pal(name="PuRd",n=8)[2:8]
    palette <- colorBin(pal_ref, domain =~covariable,bins = bins_ref,na.color = "transparent")
    popup_covar <- paste("</b>",
                         "<a href='", shape_covid_2$url,
                         "' target='_blank'>"
                         , shape_covid_2$NAME,"</a>","<br/>",
                         "REFUGEES :",round(shape_covid_2$refugees,2),"Thousands")
    title_covar <- paste("Refugees (Thousands people)","</b>","<br/>","Date :",unique(shape_covid_2$date2),"</b>","<br/>","Source : United Nations Development Program")
  }
  
  
  
  if ( outcome == "LETALITY") {
    label_Letalite <- paste(shape_covid_2$NAME,"</b>","<br/>","LR:",round(shape_covid_2$Letalite,2),"%") %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)
    leaflet(shape_covid_2,options = leafletOptions(zoomSnap = 0.25, zoomDelta=0.25)) %>%
      addScaleBar(position = "bottomright")%>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      setView(lng=11.914,lat=-0.406,zoom=2.75) %>%
      addPolygons(fillColor = ~palette(covariable),
                  stroke = TRUE,
                  weight = 0.3,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "white",
                  dashArray = "3",
                  fillOpacity = 0.7,popup = ~paste(popup_covar),
                  highlight = highlightOptions(
                    weight = 3,color = "#666",dashArray = "",
                    fillOpacity = 0.8,bringToFront = FALSE)) %>%
      addCircles(lng=~lng,lat=~lat,radius= ~(shape_covid_2$Letalite)*50000,weight=1,color = 'black',fillOpacity = 1,
                 label = label_Letalite, labelOptions = labelOptions(style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),textsize = "11px",
                                                                     direction = "right")) %>%
      addLegend(pal = palette, values = ~covariable, opacity = 0.7, title = title_covar, position = "bottomleft") -> carte
    return(carte)
  }  else if (outcome == "INCIDENCE") {
    label_incidence <- paste(shape_covid_2$NAME,"</b>","<br/>","IR :",round(shape_covid_2$ratio_cas_pop,1),
                             "per 100 000 people") %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)   
    leaflet(shape_covid_2,options = leafletOptions(zoomSnap = 0.25, zoomDelta=0.25)) %>% addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      setView(lng=11.914,lat=-0.406,zoom=2.75) %>%
      addScaleBar(position = "bottomright")%>%
      addPolygons(fillColor = ~palette(covariable),
                  stroke = TRUE,
                  weight = 0.3,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "white",
                  dashArray = "3",
                  fillOpacity = 0.7,popup = ~(popup_covar),
                  highlight = highlightOptions(
                    weight = 3,color = "#666",dashArray = "",
                    fillOpacity = 0.8,bringToFront = FALSE)) %>%
      addCircles(lng=~lng,lat=~lat,radius= ~sqrt(shape_covid_2$ratio_cas_pop)*15000,weight=1,color = 'blue',fillOpacity = 1,
                 label = label_incidence, labelOptions = labelOptions(style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),textsize = "11px",                       direction = "right")) %>%
      addLegend(pal = palette, values = ~covariable, opacity = 0.7, title = title_covar, position = "bottomleft") -> carte   
    return(carte)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, can we see the code of the function named "production_carte" ?
It is likely that this function should be sliced, one with the creation of the tiles of the map (and which should not be reactive to changes from variables) ; a second with the other elements

Comment: @LeonIpdjian I provided codes of the function `production_carte`

Comment: Thank you, I'm answering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever an input changes in a reactive function, the whole function is evaluated. In your case, even the background and the tiles are re-evaluated. So what you have to do is basically to isolate the creation of the background and the tiles. In order to do so, add the base of your `leaflet` object as argument of your map creation function :

```
creer_carte <- function(shape_covid_2){
      leaflet(shape_covid_2,options = leafletOptions(zoomSnap = 0.25, zoomDelta=0.25)) %>% 
          addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
          setView(lng=11.914,lat=-0.406,zoom=2.75) %>% 
          addScaleBar(position = "bottomright")
}

construire_shape_covid <- function(){
  
  if (mois == "APRIL") {
    data_final_mois <- subset(data_final,data_final$date2 ==ymd("2020-04-01"))
  } else if (mois == "MAY") {
    data_final_mois <- subset(data_final,data_final$date2 ==ymd("2020-05-01"))  
  } else if (mois == "JUNE") {
    data_final_mois <- subset(data_final,data_final$date2 ==ymd("2020-06-01"))  
  } else if (mois == "JULY") {
    data_final_mois <- subset(data_final,data_final$date2 ==ymd("2020-07-01")) 
  } else if (mois == "AUGUST") {
    data_final_mois <- subset(data_final,data_final$date2 ==ymd("2020-08-01")) 
  } else if (mois == "SEPTEMBER") {
    data_final_mois <- subset(data_final,data_final$date2 ==ymd("2020-09-01")) 
  } else if (mois == "OCTOBER") {
    data_final_mois <- subset(data_final,data_final$date2 == ymd("2020-10-01")) 
  } else if (mois == "NOVEMBER") {
    data_final_mois <- subset(data_final,data_final$date2 == ymd("2020-11-01")) 
  }
  
  
  data_final_mois -> shape_covid_2
  
  shape_covid_2$IDH <- as.numeric(shape_covid_2$IDH)
  shape_covid_2$density <- as.numeric(as.character(shape_covid_2$density))
  shape_covid_2$Death_blw_5 <- as.numeric(shape_covid_2$Death_blw_5)
  shape_covid_2$rate_abv_65 <- as.numeric(shape_covid_2$rate_abv_65)
  shape_covid_2$refugees <- as.numeric(shape_covid_2$refugees)
  shape_covid_2$IHDI <- as.numeric(shape_covid_2$IHDI)
  shape_covid_2$ratio_cas_pop<-as.numeric(shape_covid_2$ratio_cas_pop)
  shape_covid_2$Letalite<-as.numeric(shape_covid_2$Letalite)
}

new_production_carte <- function(outcome,covar,mois,carte_base) {
  
  # coef_rad = 1
  # outcome <- as.character(outcome)
  # covar <- as.character(covar)
  # mois <- as.character(mois)
  title_covar =""
  
  shape_covid_2 <- construire_shape_covid()
  if ( covar == "IDH") {
    covariable <- shape_covid_2$IDH
    bins_idh <- c(0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9)
    pal_idh <- brewer.pal(name="BuGn",n=8)[2:8]
    palette <- colorBin(pal_idh, domain =~covariable,bins = bins_idh,na.color = "transparent")
    popup_covar <- paste("</b>",
                         "<a href='", shape_covid_2$url,
                         "' target='_blank'>"
                         , shape_covid_2$NAME,"</a>","<br/>",
                           "HDI :",round(shape_covid_2$IDH,2)) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)
    title_covar <- paste("Human Development Indicator","</b>","<br/>","Date :",unique(shape_covid_2$date2),"</b>","<br/>","Source : United Nations Development Program")
  } else if (covar == "POPULATION DENSITY") {
    covariable <- shape_covid_2$density
    bins_density <- c(2,20,60,100,200,300,400,650)
    pal_density <- brewer.pal(name="BuPu",n=8)[2:8]
    palette <- colorBin(pal_density, domain =~covariable,bins = bins_density,na.color = "transparent")
    popup_covar <- paste("</b>",
                         "<a href='", shape_covid_2$url,
                         "' target='_blank'>"
                         , shape_covid_2$NAME,"</a>","<br/>","Pop Density :",
                         round(shape_covid_2$density,2),"people/sq.km")
    title_covar <- paste("Population Density (people/sq.km)","</b>","<br/>","Date :",
                         unique(shape_covid_2$date2),"</b>","<br/>","Source : World Databank")
  } else if (covar == "EQUALITY LEVEL") {
    covariable <- shape_covid_2$IHDI
    bins_ineq <- c(0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7)
    pal_ineq <- brewer.pal(name="YlGn",n=6)[2:6]
    palette <- colorBin(pal_ineq, domain =~covariable,bins = bins_ineq,na.color = "transparent")
    popup_covar <- paste("</b>",
                         "<a href='", shape_covid_2$url,
                         "' target='_blank'>"
                         , shape_covid_2$NAME,"</a>","<br/>",
                         "Equality Level :",round(shape_covid_2$IHDI,2))
    title_covar <- paste("Equality Level Indicator","</b>","<br/>","Date :",unique(shape_covid_2$date2),"Source : ?")
  } else if (covar == "UNDER 5 MORTALITY") {
    covariable <- shape_covid_2$Death_blw_5
    bins_u5 <- c(10,20,30,40,60,80,100,120)
    pal_u5 <- brewer.pal(name="YlOrRd",n=8)[2:8]
    palette <- colorBin(pal_u5, domain =~covariable,bins = bins_u5,na.color = "transparent")
    popup_covar <- paste("</b>",
                         "<a href='", shape_covid_2$url,
                         "' target='_blank'>"
                         , shape_covid_2$NAME,"</a>","<br/>",
                         "Under 5 mortality :",round(shape_covid_2$Death_blw_5,2),"child/1000 birth")
    title_covar <- paste("Under five mortality rate (child/1000 birth)","</b>","<br/>","Date:",unique(shape_covid_2$date2),"</b>","<br/>",
                         "Source : UNICEF")
  } else if (covar == "AGE ABOVE 65") {
    covariable <- shape_covid_2$rate_abv_65
    bins_above_65 <- c(1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,7,12)
    pal_above_65 <- brewer.pal(name="YlGnBu",n=8)[2:8]
    palette <- colorBin(pal_above_65, domain =~covariable,bins = bins_above_65,na.color = "transparent")
    popup_covar <- paste("</b>",
                         "<a href='", shape_covid_2$url,
                         "' target='_blank'>"
                         , shape_covid_2$NAME,"</a>","<br/>",
                         "Above 65 pop rate :",round(shape_covid_2$rate_abv_65,2),"%")
    title_covar <- paste("Above 65 population rate (%)","</b>","<br/>","Date :",unique(shape_covid_2$date2),"</b>","<br/>","Source : United Nations Development Program")
  } else if (covar == "REFUGEES") {
    covariable <- shape_covid_2$refugees
    bins_ref <- c(0,0.3,0.6,3,7.2,27,100,950)
    pal_ref <- brewer.pal(name="PuRd",n=8)[2:8]
    palette <- colorBin(pal_ref, domain =~covariable,bins = bins_ref,na.color = "transparent")
    popup_covar <- paste("</b>",
                         "<a href='", shape_covid_2$url,
                         "' target='_blank'>"
                         , shape_covid_2$NAME,"</a>","<br/>",
                         "REFUGEES :",round(shape_covid_2$refugees,2),"Thousands")
    title_covar <- paste("Refugees (Thousands people)","</b>","<br/>","Date :",unique(shape_covid_2$date2),"</b>","<br/>","Source : United Nations Development Program")
  }
  
  
  
  if ( outcome == "LETALITY") {
    label_Letalite <- paste(shape_covid_2$NAME,"</b>","<br/>","LR:",round(shape_covid_2$Letalite,2),"%") %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)
    carte_base %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      setView(lng=11.914,lat=-0.406,zoom=2.75) %>%
      addPolygons(fillColor = ~palette(covariable),
                  stroke = TRUE,
                  weight = 0.3,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "white",
                  dashArray = "3",
                  fillOpacity = 0.7,popup = ~paste(popup_covar),
                  highlight = highlightOptions(
                    weight = 3,color = "#666",dashArray = "",
                    fillOpacity = 0.8,bringToFront = FALSE)) %>%
      addCircles(lng=~lng,lat=~lat,radius= ~(shape_covid_2$Letalite)*50000,weight=1,color = 'black',fillOpacity = 1,
                 label = label_Letalite, labelOptions = labelOptions(style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),textsize = "11px",
                                                                     direction = "right")) %>%
      addLegend(pal = palette, values = ~covariable, opacity = 0.7, title = title_covar, position = "bottomleft") -> carte
    return(carte)
  }  else if (outcome == "INCIDENCE") {
    label_incidence <- paste(shape_covid_2$NAME,"</b>","<br/>","IR :",round(shape_covid_2$ratio_cas_pop,1),
                             "per 100 000 people") %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)   
    carte_base %>%
      addPolygons(fillColor = ~palette(covariable),
                  stroke = TRUE,
                  weight = 0.3,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "white",
                  dashArray = "3",
                  fillOpacity = 0.7,popup = ~(popup_covar),
                  highlight = highlightOptions(
                    weight = 3,color = "#666",dashArray = "",
                    fillOpacity = 0.8,bringToFront = FALSE)) %>%
      addCircles(lng=~lng,lat=~lat,radius= ~sqrt(shape_covid_2$ratio_cas_pop)*15000,weight=1,color = 'blue',fillOpacity = 1,
                 label = label_incidence, labelOptions = labelOptions(style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),textsize = "11px",                       direction = "right")) %>%
      addLegend(pal = palette, values = ~covariable, opacity = 0.7, title = title_covar, position = "bottomleft") -> carte   
    return(carte)
  }
}
```

Then into your shiny server part :

```
   shape_covid_2 <- reactive(construire_shape_covid())
   carte_fond <- reactive(creer_carte(shape_covid_2()))

   output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    production_carte(outcome = outcome(),covar = covariable(),
                     mois = mois(), carte_base = carte_fond() ) })
```

Maybe this won't work because I hardly could read your code properly, but I think you will see the main point.

Comment: I have this error message `Warning: Error in construire_shape_covid: object 'mois' not found`